# How to use multiple RS in AWK

Tags: awk

Thanks for the support, I am trying to extract a specific pattern from the log my log sample is below

and I want the output like below.

```
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT -
RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA.
PROPERTY -
RECORD
```

I tried using AWK but its helping to get half the output not able to use multiple RS.

```
[root@localhost ~]# awk 'BEGIN{RS="*"; FS="-1/NO,"}NF>1{print $NF}' log2
 PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY -
RECORD
[root@localhost ~]#
```

Need your advice on this.

Comment: Which strings separate records, i.e. what are those multiple RS values you want to use? It LOOKS like you should just set `RS="RECORD"` if you have GNU awk. Also explain how a script should know to put `PROPERTY -` on a separate line  in the second record. There must be some kind of structure/organization to your data, tell us what that is so we can best help you.  [edit] your question to provide all missing information, don't add it in comments.

Comment: We might not have accreditation in software engineering, but at the very least It should be illegal for people to design data exchange formats, who are not educated and licensed for the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which strings you want to use as `RS` or why newlines appear in some parts of your output but not others but maybe one of these is what you're trying to do, or at least will give you an idea on how to do whatever it is you're trying to do, using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, and `RT`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[#*]"} {$1=$1} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT - RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY - RECORD
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[#*]"} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT - RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY -
RECORD
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[#*]"} {$NF=ORS $NF} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT -
RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY -
RECORD
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="RECORD"} {$NF=$NF " " RT} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT - RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY - RECORD
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="RECORD"} {$0=$0 RT} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT - RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY -
RECORD
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="RECORD"} {$NF=$NF ORS RT} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT -
RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA. PROPERTY -
RECORD
```

There are, of course, many other possibilities, including this which produces the output you show but there's probably a better way to do that if we knew why this is the output you show:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="RECORD"} {$NF=$NF ORS RT; gsub(/PROPERTY/,ORS"&"); sub(ORS"PROPERTY","PROPERTY")} sub(".*-1/NO, ","")' log2
LIMIT: 1:1=MISSING LIMIT -
RECORD
PROPERTY: 1: 1=MISSING AA.
PROPERTY -
RECORD
```